# How do I learn which AEM CoralUI version I am using?

Tags: adobe-exprience-manager

This [CoralUI documentation page](https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-5/coral-ui/coralui3/documentation.html#coralUI3Migration) has a migration guide from earlier versions of CoralUI.

How do I learn which Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) CoralUI version I am using?

Answer (score 0):

I think I can see it by going into [CRXDE package manager](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/administering/contentmanagement/package-manager.html?lang=en#creating-a-new-package) and using the browser search (not the Search packages field) for `coral`:

[image: Screenshot of crx-packmgr package search]